# react-router-dom v4 link to nested route too much recursion

Tags: react-redux, react-router-v4

Currently whenever I try to link to a nested route that renders a new element, I get the too much recursion error. For obvious reasons it keeps rerendering this component. Where does one put a nested route so it doesnt get rendered over and over again?

```
      redirectAddSurvey(){
        this.props.addSurvey("Titel Survey", "Survey beschrijving");  this.props.history.push(`/survey/${this.props.match.params.action}`);
      }

    render() {
        return (
          <div id="newSurveyButton">
            <RaisedButton containerElement={  <Link to={`${this.props.match.url}/new`} />} label="Add new Survey" onClick={() => this.redirectAddSurvey()}></RaisedButton>
            <Route path={`${this.props.match.url}/:action`} render={props => <Survey title="Helloworld" desc="HelloDesc" {...props} />} />
          </div>
        );
    }
}

// Get apps state and pass it as props to SurveyList
//      > whenever state changes, the SurveyList will automatically re-render
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        surveys: state.surveys,
      };
}
```

Updated:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div id="newSurveyButton">
        <RaisedButton  label="Add new Survey" onClick={() => this.redirectAddSurvey()}></RaisedButton>
        <Link to={`${this.props.match.url}/new`} />
        <Route path={`survey/:action`} render={props => <Survey title="Helloworld" desc="HelloDesc" {...props} />} />
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I think, the problem is here `<Route path={\`${this.props.match.url}/:action\`} render={props => <Survey title="Helloworld" desc="HelloDesc" {...props} />} />` since `path={\`${this.props.match.url}/:action\`}` will give a new Route path on every URL change. I would rather suggest you to write something like `path={\`survey/:action\`}`

Comment: Also onClick is not a prop on RaisedButton, You should rather use onTouchTap and why do you have a dynamic route on button click as well a link, that can also cause the problem

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I did not know that. When I change the paths the survey doesnt get rendered anymore. Any idea why that may be?

Comment: It should depend on how the link is updated. Also are you getting any errors.

Comment: No errors unfortunately. I edited main post up to date render.

Comment: There are a few questions that I have, if you are using redirectAddSurvey and you are getting the params to pass to the current component then what is the need for dynmica routing

Comment: I would like to be able to navigate to a survey page by url. At this stage it wouldnt really be necessary. But I wanted to first be able to render a Survey from a route before implementing that.Like so: survey/1

Comment: Turns out it was something that was getting rendered in Survey. My apologies you couldnt have known. I should have provided more info after all.

Comment: Glad, you were able to solve the problem :)